# Obtain a new hex color value from "alpha blending" the originial color in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-imaging-library

simply, given an initial color "#1010CA" and an alpha factor 0.5, how can I get the final color that is shown on the plot in terms of `color="#1010CA", alpha=0.5`?

or more straightforwardly, what should I fill in

```
plot(x, y, color=__)
```

so that it is equivalent (at least visually) to

```
plot(x, y, color="#1010CA", alpha=0.5)
```

? I guess it shouldn't be a python question, instead how to manipulate the rgb colors by some factor to damp it, but forgive my ignorance in color palettes...

**EDIT**

Here is the current solution I opt for after taking @Blender's answer

```
import matplotlib
import numpy as np
def alpha_blending(hex_color, alpha) :
    """ alpha blending as if on the white background.
    """
    foreground_tuple  = matplotlib.colors.hex2color(hex_color)
    foreground_arr = np.array(foreground_tuple)
    final = tuple( (1. -  alpha) + foreground_arr*alpha )
    return(final)
```

Comment: You're just making the color twice as dark. Add `(0.5, 0.5, 0.5)` to it.

Comment: @Blender you are right, I deleted those codes, but is "0.5 + foregroud/2" is exact or an approximation?

Comment: Lol, I actually guessed it right on the first try (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing#Alpha_blending). Yes, that's the exact solution for the background color of white adn a transparency of 0.5. With `numpy`, you can just do `tuple(0.5 + numpy.array(foreground_tuple) / 2.0)` and plug that back into the Matplotlib color parameter.

Comment: @Blender Kudos! You indeed "blend" colors well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get a "final color" without the background color as well.

But for rendering alpha transparency, I would *guess* that a weighted sum would work:

```
final = (1 - alpha) * background + alpha * foreground
```

So if your color is white and your `alpha = 0.5`, you can do:

```
final = rgb(0.5, 0.5, 0.5) + foreground / 2
```

Matplotlib accepts RGB tuples so you can make an opacity flattening function pretty easily. Why you need to do this, however, is not something I can answer.

Comment: yeah, I think you are right, I haven't thought about the background yet, only assume it to be white at this moment...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that it's a blend of two colors (foreground and background) that influences the final pixel color. If you're starting from white color as you background, converting your foreground color to **HSI** colorspace ([http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIELAB)) and using **I** as your alpha channel can get you close. For even closer match, you can use **L*a*b** colorspace (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIELAB) and change **L** to match your transparency ratio.

Comment: so is there a quick & dirty solution in python based on this color space conversion? looks like I need more than 20 minutes to parse the material and get it done in python.